# Replace String in python with matched pattern

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have to remove any punctuation marks from the start and at the end of the word.
I am using `re.sub` to do it.

```
re.sub(r'(\w.+)(?=[^\w]$)','\1',text)
```

Grouping not working out - all I get is `☺.` for `Mihir4.` in command line

Comment: please give a better example of the input and the expected output. can there be multiple punctuation characters at the start/end of a word? can the string consist of more than one word?

Comment: For multiple character take this regex pattern `[\w+\-]+` which will give me words only separated by a `-`. But my question is how to replace a string with any pattern .

Comment: Alternatively, you could also use `str.strip` (as long as `text` is just that one word)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have string with multiple words, such as

```
text = ".adfdf. 'df' !3423? ld! :sdsd"
```

this will do the trick (it will also work for single words, of course):

```
>>> re.sub(r'[^\w\s]*(\w+)[^\w\s]*', r'\1', text)
'adfdf df 3423 ld sdsd'
```

Notice the r in `r'\1'`. This is equivalent to `'\\1'`.

```
>>> re.sub(r'[^\w\s]*(\w+)[^\w\s]*', '\\1', text)
'adfdf df 3423 ld sdsd'
```

Further reading: [the backslash plague](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#the-backslash-plague)

Answer (score 1):

The string literal `'\1'` is equivalent to `'\x01'`. You need to escape it or use raw string literal to mean backreference group 1.

BTW, you don't need to use the capturing group.

```
>>> re.sub(r'^[^-\w]+|[^-\w]$', '', 'Mihir4.')
'Mihir4'
```

Comment: Mihir4. is not static. Words are coming from a list.

Comment: @mjosh, You can replace `'Mihir4.'` with `text` as you did in the question.